# RecyclerView - Keep selected position after adding new elements

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

The question is plain simple: As I add new elements to the adapter to the beginning of the adapter's list, how can I keep the RecyclerView with the same position selected?

I've been playing with the scrolling methods but I can't find the right solution.

Thank you

Comment: Do you add new item after clicking to recycleviewr's actual item or the actual item is the top item on display ?

Comment: I didn't understood the question .. @eurosecom

Comment: What does it mean "the same position selected" ? The new added item on the top of list ?